# Write Statement in Relational Algebra

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

I am having issues trying to write the following statement in relational algebra:

```
select A.name, A.gender, A.class, B.sid from A,B;
```

I dont know if it helps but A and B are connect through the sid primary key

When I was messing around with it I came up with this:

```
π A.name, A.gender, A.class, B.sid (A,B)
```

But I am not sure if that is correct

Comment: There are many RAs (relational algebras).They differ in operators & even what a relation is.  Give a reference and/or definition for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. Define "write in"--Same result? Same structure? How does a table correspond to a relation? What about nulls? PS No RA uses comma as an operator. So you don't seem to have made any effort to inform yourself. See [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1):

The notation `FROM A,B` in SQL is not frequently used as some time ago, it corresponds to the cartesian product (which is now more commonly written as `FROM A CROSS JOIN B`) that concatenates every tuple of `A` with all the tuples of `B`.

In relational algebra it can be expressed through the operator for the cartesian product, `x`, so the query can be translated as:

```
π A.name, A.gender, A.class, B.sid (A x B)
```

Note that in the relational algebra the two tables arguments of the `x` operator are in general required with attributes all different.

Finally, note also that the fact that the tuples of the two relations are connected trough some attribute (like for instance a foreign key) is ignored by this operator.

Comment: " tuples of the two relations are connected trough a foreign key is not used" True-ish. But if the two relations both have an attribute named `sid` (or in general same-named attributes), then a Cartesian product will fail. GeeGee doesn't give us the schema of the relations; so we don't know.

Comment: @AntC & Renzo Versions of RA with lists as headings can & do have a product operator taking inputs sharing attribute names. That is why they typically involve aliases & dots. As I've said before, there's no point in answering with an arbitrary fragment of the necessary precis on algebra options; tell the asker to define their algebra. Here the answerer talks about an operator denoted by a symbol & a name but they don't even know what operator they are talking about.